# Parsing json (2 arrays) in Android

Tags: android, arrays, json, parsing

I need to parse a JSON with two arrays.

resp: `{"attending": [], "people": []}`

I tried this

```
JSONObject AttendingArray = new JSONObject(resp);               
JSONArray ParkArray = new JSONArray("people");
JSONArray AttendingArray = new JSONArray("attending");
```

But it doesn't work

```
12-01 22:47:53.074: WARN/System.err(30814): org.json.JSONException: Value people of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
```

Thanks!

Comment: Which json api are you using?  Which line causes the exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(resp);               
JSONArray ParkArray = new JSONArray(obj.getString("people"));
JSONArray AttendingArray = new JSONArray(obj.getString("attending"));
```

You must pass actual JSON to the `JSONArray` constructor, not just the name of the json array - the `new JSONArray` constructor call doesn't know about the response, so you need to give it some data, not just "people"

Comment: Ah sorry, was just doing it from memory woops